# UITextField textAlignment reverse while edit

Tags: ios, uitextfield, text-alignment

i got a custom UITextField class

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.textColor = [UIColor mtcTurquoise];
    self.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    if (IS_IPAD) {
        self.font = [UIFont arialBoldWithSize:14];
    }
    else{
        self.font = [UIFont arialBoldWithSize:13];
    }
}
```

When i add Once in UITableViewCell i got some alignment issue : placeholder & unedit fields are well align. But When i edit the field there is a revers alignment

[image: see bellow]

```
static NSString * MTCInfosEditTableViewCellID = @"MTCInfosEditTableViewCell";
        MTCInfosEditTableViewCell *cell = (MTCInfosEditTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MTCInfosEditTableViewCellID];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTCInfosEditTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
            cell = (MTCInfosEditTableViewCell *)c.view;
        }
cell.infoTF.delegate = self;





- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    MTCTextFlieldTableView * tf = (MTCTextFlieldTableView *)textField;

    if ([tf.table isEqual:mainTable] && tf.indexPath.section == 0) {
        ((MTCInfos *)[self.arrayInfoUser objectAtIndex:tf.indexPath.row]).value = tf.text;
    }
    else if ([tf.table isEqual:secondTable] && tf.indexPath.section == 0) {
        ((MTCInfos *)[self.arrayPasswordUser objectAtIndex:tf.indexPath.row]).value = tf.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: add some code of textfield delegate or cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: is it the third cell u want to right align?

Comment: i edit my code with delegates.
No i want all left align. but while edit the align goes left ...

Comment: third cell right alignment will come right side to cell.if you want like first two cells set left alignment

Comment: i add cell. infoTF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

-> http://i.imgur.com/ZViRgLd.png

the right aligment is only